# Using database values in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Basically what i'm trying to accomplish is a query like this but using QuerySet:

```
SELECT value1, value2 FROM table WHERE value1 > value2
```

How do i do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The [Django documentation about `queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) is pretty detailed. At which point are you stuck ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) to have a query field refer to another.

```
from django.db.models import F
Entry.objects.filter( n_comments__gt=F('n_pingbacks') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`F()` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters)

In your example it would look like:

```
from django.db.models import F
Table.objects.filter(value1__gt=F('value2')).values('value1', 'value2')
```